# Why does angular-cli create component/shared/index.ts?

Tags: angular, shared, angular-cli

If I run this:

```
ng g component components/blogs
```

I get

```
app
+--components
| +--blogs
| |  +--shared
| |  |  +--index.ts              // what's this for?
| |  +--blogs.component.css
| |  +--blogs.component.html
| |  +--blogs.component.ts
| |  +--blogs.component.spec.ts  // unit tests!
| |  +--index.ts
```

I understand the rest, but what is the `/blogs/shared/index.ts` for?  Why does a component have a shared folder if that component folder is just for the component?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The idea of the `index.ts` file in the shared dir is something called a barrel.

The goal of the barrel it to consolidate imports. It will export the items contained within shared to make the imports in `blogs.component.ts` cleaner...

**app/components/blogs/shared/blogs.service.ts**

```
export class BlogsService { ... }
```

**app/components/blogs/shared/blog.model.ts**

```
export class Blog { ... }
```

**app/components/blogs/shared/index.ts**

```
export * from './blogs.service';
export * from './blog.model';
```

**app/components/blogs/blogs.component.ts**

```
// without barrel
import { BlogsSerivce } from './shared/blogs.service';
import { Blog } from './shared/blog.model';

// with barrel
import { BlogService, Blog } from './shared';
```

And if you can imagine this becomes much more consolidated as you add more components/services/directives/models.

**REFERENCE** You can read about barrels in the official [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel) (Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer)