# angular2 rc6 - systemjs.config.js using subfolder /src/app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs

On the angular2 quick start page:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

with Angular2 rc6 , file systemjs.config.js has changed . I'm trying to change the folder /app/ accord to angular quick start   by /src/app accord my app, so i'm not sure what i must to change in this file. I've tried some paths but it's not working, anyone can explain more about this file and how I use the paths. in this configuration i dont care about production or /dist , because i'm just testing angular. 
I was working before with webpack starters or angular-cli but new versions angular broke those packages, so i want to stay simple.

src/app/systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // angular testing umd bundles
      '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }     from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Configuration } from './app.constants';
import { routing }        from './app.routing';
import { AccountListComponent } from './accounts/account-list/account-list.component';
import { AccountDetailComponent } from './accounts/account-detail/account-detail.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountListComponent,
    AccountDetailComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [Configuration],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

src/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

/src/main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule, environment } from './index';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

./index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ng2</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend use webpack and not systemjs, because support barrel concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682372/why-does-angular-cli-create-component-shared-index-ts , i've found the guide of angular with webpack is working very well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682372/why-does-angular-cli-create-component-shared-index-ts  , another starters and angular-cli don't support yet rc6 version

Comment: That is easily the worst reason to use one over the other that I have ever heard. They are fundamentally different tools with different approaches and they each have strengths and weaknesses. Barrels, on the other hand are a bad coding convention that somehow got infused into the minds of Angular 2 users. Probably because of the framework's lack of a proper service provider abstraction. 8 months later and it still doesn't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the new systemjs.config from angular to be a bit more messy. This is what i use and it works great:

```
(function(global) {
    var map = {
            'app': 'src/app',
            '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
        },
        packages = {
            'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {main: './index.js',defaultExtension:'js'}
            'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
        },
        ngPackageNames = [
            'common',
            'compiler',
            'core',
            'http',
            'platform-browser',
            'platform-browser-dynamic',
            'router',
            'forms'
        ],

        tests = [
            'core/testing',
            'common/testing',
            'compiler/testing',
            'platform-browser/testing',
            'platform-browser-dynamic/testing',
            'http/testing',
            'router/testing',
            'forms/testing'
        ];

    function packUmd(pkgName) {packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }}

    ngPackageNames.forEach(packUmd);

    tests.forEach(function (test) {
        return packages['@angular/'+ test] = { main: '/bundles/' + test.replace(/\//, '-') + '.umd.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    })

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

I think this looks much cleaner and understandable. The only thing you need to change if your app folder changes is: `'app': 'path-to-app/app'`

Comment: thanks now it's working, the only problem i have it's angular don't find my .js that are in subfolders , like http://localhost:3000/src/app/dashboard.js 404 (Not Found) , but there is in http://localhost:3000/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.js, i don't understand how i can configure systemjs.config.js to do that

Comment: That can't be right. I have the same configuration and everything works fine. Are you sure that something else isn't causing the error?

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm sure i'm missing something; i've updated my question with the source files. if you can realize the error. webpack make one file in one folder all the .ts compiled files (.js), how does work systemjs.config ? load every js, but where?

Comment: I'm happy to help. Sorry it still isn't working for you. You can achieve a similar build using systemjs-builder. Here is the link:https://github.com/systemjs/builder

Answer (score 0):

To load modules in `NodeJS`, install `SystemJS` with:

`npm install systemjs`

If transpiling ES modules, install the transpiler plugin following the instructions from the transpiler project page.